# Resize SVG bootstrap icon

Tags: css, svg, bootstrap-icons

Is it possible to resize a [bootstrap icon](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/) in CSS?
The icons are SVG.
I am adding the icon in HTML, not via CSS.

Comment: You have added the SVG inline code of the icon to HTML?

Answer (score 5):

Changing the font-size solve it for me:

```
<i class='bi bi-search' style='font-size:26px;'></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own css class:

```css
svg.bi.bi-icon-sm {
    height: 8px !important;
    width: 8px !important;
}

...

svg.bi.bi-icon-xl {
    height: 32px !important;
    width: 32px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the bootstrap predefined font sizes
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/text/#font-size

E.g.:

```
<span class="bi bi-box-arrow-right fs-3"></span>
```